# TSQL DDL constraint error: "Line 12: Incorrect syntax near '('."

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, ddl

I'm trying to create a table. Here's the creation DDL. I'm encountering an error when I run this on SQL Server 2005 MSDE. I have no idea why - it works fine on 2008/2012.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CuCompanyHolidays](
    [HolidayID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [HolidayName] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [HolidayDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [PartOff] [float] NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_cuCompanyHolidays] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [HolidayID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

> Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   Line 12: Incorrect syntax near '('.

Here's the line the error is highlighting:

> )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON PRIMARY

How can I resolve this?

Comment: @MitchWheat still it will execute even with brackets that's why i deleted the answer. hehe [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/190bc/1)

Comment: There isn't a Server 2005 MSDE. What does `@@VERSION` say? Either 2000 MSDE or 2005 Express.

Comment: The `[ WITH ( <table_option> [ ,...n ] ) ]` part is not supported on SQL Server 2000. You are probably connected to a SQL Server 2000 server.